# Table not being filled from Ajax Call using Datatables plug-in for jQuery

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, datatables

The ajax request is returning the following data

```
    [{"ID":40,"Date":"\/Date(1407999600000)\/"},{"ID":39,"Date":"\/Date(1409036400000)\/"}
```

The HTML is:

```
<table id="bookings-table" class="display">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

And the javascript is

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#bookings-table').dataTable({
        "ajaxSource": "/manager/Booking/GetBookings",
        "columns": [
        { "data": "ID" },
        { "data": "Date" }
        ]
    });
});
```

Any idea why the table is not being filled

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at their [docs](http://www.datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html), I believe your json has to be formatted as so.

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "ID": 40,
            "Date": "\/Date(1407999600000)\/"
        },
        {
            "ID": 39,
            "Date": "\/Date(1409036400000)\/"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript error

```
    $('#bookings-table').dataTable({
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/manager/Booking/GetBookings",
            "dataSrc": ""
        },
```

Sorted it all columns now bind